# Elasticsearch "no requests added" Bulk API Error

Tags: elasticsearch

Trying to get Bulk Update to work on ES 1.0.1.

I am within Postman posting the following:

**URL** `POST` or `PUT` to `http://localhost:9200/_bulk`

**Request Body**:

```
{ "update" : { "_index" : "test_people", "_type" : "person", "_id" : "1" }} \n
{ "doc" : { "name":"hi", "age":100 }} \n
```

I have tried it with and without the `\n`. I always get

```
{
    "error": "ActionRequestValidationException[Validation Failed: 1: no requests added;]",
    "status": 500
}
```

It also does the same thing on a create using the data:

```
{
  "create": {
    "_index": "test_people",
    "_type": "person",
    "_id": "1"
  }
}
{
  "name": "hi",
  "age": 100
}
```

#### Update

I have tried this on a Mac, PC, and Linux and I am continually getting the same error.

Answer (score 117, accepted):

Even though i had `\n` on the last line I literally HAD to have a full carriage return after my last json line.

The following worked:

```
{ "update" : { "_index" : "test_people", "_type" : "person", "_id" : "1" }} \n
{ "doc" : { "name":"hi", "age":100 }}
```

So there needs to be an empty line below the `"doc"` line.

Comment: You mean **instead** of having `\n`at the end of the last line we need to have a carriage return (`Enter` key on Windows).

Comment: Two `\n`s at the end is fine, no need for a `\r`.

Comment: In postman also, you can add new blank line after body it works. Thanks

Answer (score 22):

True that one blank **new line** , after document row does the trick.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

If you're using cURL, you must have a blank line at the end of your bulk items and you **must use `--data-binary` (instead of plain `-d`)**. For example, suppose you have a file called `bulk` that has:

```
{ "index" : { "_id" : 1 } }
{ "accounts" : ["hillary", "sidney"]}
{ "index" : { "_id" : 2 } }
{ "accounts" : ["hillary", "donald"]}
{ "index" : { "_id" : 3 } }
{ "accounts" : ["vladimir", "donald"]}
```

Ensure the file is terminated by a blank line, then post with cURL:

```
curl -i -XPOST -H'content-type: application/json' 'localhost:9200/emails/message/_bulk?refresh&pretty' --data-binary @bulk
```