# Where to specify the file path while running elasticsearch Bulk API

Tags: json, elasticsearch, postman

I am new to elasticsearch, running elasticsearch from chrome:extension- Postman.
I want to enter bulk data into it, from JSON using Bulk API. 
I have seen the command :

```
curl -s -XPOST 'http://jfblouvmlxecs01:9200/_bulk' --data-binary @bulk.json
```

While using Postman, I do not know where to store the file @bulk.json,
Currently I have stored it at `C:\elasticsearch-1.5.2\bin\bulk.JSON`

The command I am using is `http://localhost:9200/_bulk --data-binary @bulk.JSON`
This is throwing following error:

> "error": "InvalidIndexNameException[[_bulk --data-binary @bulk.JSON] Invalid index name [_bulk --data-binary @bulk.JSON], must not contain the following characters [\, /, *, ?, \", <, >, |,  , ,]]",
>   "status": 400 }

Can someone please suggest, where to store the JSON file.
Or am I doing something wrong here.

Comment: What you're seeing works for `curl` commands. In Postman, it works differently, simply put the content of your bulk.json file in the body. See this answer which should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22996337/elasticsearch-no-requests-added-bulk-api-error

Comment: Also see this link which shows exactly how to call `_bulk` from Postman: http://red-badger.com/blog/2013/11/08/getting-started-with-elasticsearch/

Comment: Thank you Val. Your answers really helped me!
My JSON file is huge, so pasting it in Postman body was creating some problems , and Postman ends up crashing. 
I guess the only was is to split the JSON file and paste it.
Thanks once again!

Comment: Why not going the `curl` way if your file is too big?

Comment: I have never used `curl` before. Just started experimenting with it now.

Comment: Give it a try, it's straightforward for what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can store your file anywhere and then pass the path like this:

```
curl -s -XPOST 'http://jfblouvmlxecs01:9200/_bulk' --data-binary @"/blah/blah/bulk.json"
```

If you want to do it with postman there is an answer [here that explains how](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15936616/import-index-a-json-file-into-elasticsearch)

But if you want to use this for large data, I wouldn't recommend using postman or sense. Use curl directly or [logstash](https://www.elastic.co/products/logstash)

See also this: https://github.com/taskrabbit/elasticsearch-dump