# Adding documents using Bulk api in elasticsearch 5.1.1 through cerebro0.4.1 plugin

Tags: elasticsearch-5, elasticsearch-bulk-api

When i tried to post the below code in cerebro plugin

```
POST /_bulk    
    { 
         "index" : { "_index" : "test", "_type" : "type1", "_id" : "1" },
         "field1" : "value1" ,
         "delete" : { "_index" : "test", "_type" : "type1", "_id" : "2" },
         "create" : { "_index" : "test", "_type" : "type1", "_id" : "3" },
         "field2" : "value3" ,
         "update" : {"_id" : "1", "_type" : "type1", "_index" : "test"},
         "doc" : {"field3" : "value2"} 
}
```

It is showing error like this in cerebro plugin:

```
    {
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "action_request_validation_exception",
        "reason": "Validation Failed: 1: no requests added;"
      }
    ],
    "type": "action_request_validation_exception",
    "reason": "Validation Failed: 1: no requests added;"
  },
  "status": 400
}
```

Comment: Cerebro doesn't support the bulk format right now, I've [filed an issue](https://github.com/lmenezes/cerebro/issues/130), we'll see what unfolds.

Comment: You can try in kopf in this bulk api works..

Comment: Yes, it used to work in kopf, but that was a site plugin. cerebro is now a full-fledge scala app and has been completely rewritten, some features are still missing.

Answer (score 1):

What if you have your `json` body ending up with a new line `\n` character, which could look something like this:

```
    { "index" : { "_index" : "test", "_type" : "type1", "_id" : "1" }}
    {"field1" : "value1"}
    {"delete" : { "_index" : "test", "_type" : "type1", "_id" : "2" }}
    {"create" : { "_index" : "test", "_type" : "type1", "_id" : "3" }}
    {"field2" : "value3"}
    {"update" : {"_id" : "1", "_type" : "type1", "_index" : "test"}}
    {"doc" : {"field3" : "value2"}}\n
```

Also make sure that you have your indentation properly. As per the [doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html#docs-bulk), you should be having the new line character at the end of your `json`. You may have a look at this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22996337/elasticsearch-no-requests-added-bulk-api-error) as well. Hope it helps!

Comment: I tried giving \n in at the end of doc but cerebro plugin is showing it as bad syntax. I indented the content nothing helped..