# Elasticsearch Java multisearch JSON

Tags: elasticsearch, resttemplate

I am trying to do a post to elasticsearch API.

I need to do a multisearch, because I need to query in many indexes.

I am using Java8 + resttemplate to do it.

See the code below:

```
      StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("{\"index\" : \"indexname\", \"type\": \"typename\"}");
        sb.append("{\"query\" : {\"match_all\" : {}}, \"from\" : 0, \"size\" : 10}");
        sb.append("{\"index\" : \"indexname\", \"type\": \"typename\"}");
        sb.append("{\"query\" : {\"match_all\" : {}}}\n");

        String query = sb.toString();

        String fullURL = "http://esHost/_msearch";

        log.debug("URL to search: {}.", fullURL);
        log.info(">>>>" + query);

        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.add("Content-Type", "application/x-ndjson");

        HttpEntity<String> request = new HttpEntity<>(query, headers);

        Map map = restTemplate.postForObject(fullURL, request, Map.class);
...
```

When I do the same query to the same host using CURLS, it is ok, but using Java I can not.
See the error:

```
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"action_request_validation_exception","reason":"Validation Failed: 1: no requests added;"}],"type":"action_request_validation_exception","reason":"Validation Failed: 1: no requests added;"},"status":400}
```

I read that JSON needs \n, \r, I tried any possibilities but does not work.

How I build my "query value" to send for _msearch API?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Elasticsearch "no requests added" Bulk API Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22996337/elasticsearch-no-requests-added-bulk-api-error)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem using the follow code:

```
private static final String NEW_LINE = System.getProperty("line.separator");

        sb.append("{\"index\" : \"indexname\", \"type\": \"typename\"}").append(NEW_LINE)
        sb.append("{\"query\" : {\"match_all\" : {}}, \"from\" : 0, \"size\" : 10}").append(NEW_LINE)
        sb.append("{\"index\" : \"indexname\", \"type\": \"typename\"}").append(NEW_LINE)
        sb.append("{\"query\" : {\"match_all\" : {}}}\n").append(NEW_LINE);
```

In this case will work in any OS.

Answer (score 0):

This will be a problem on Windows systems, because the NDJSON format explicitly uses a '\n' character for the delimiter. On Windows, you will be looking for {'\r', '\n'} which will not be found unless you likely wrote it.